# Strapi v4 how does branch between entityService object

Tags: strapi

I am using Strapi v4 and try to branch between entityService object like this:

```
if (strapi.entityService.findOne("api::post.post", post_id) !== null) {
      console.log('update')
} else {
      console.log('create')                        
}
```

Some of the object null show in terminal but it does not work.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You have to use `await strapi.entity….`